# How to assign value to id?

Tags: javascript

I have one string name as id in my .aspx.cs page and one JavaScript function SetValue(val) on .aspx page in which I have to assign val to that id. How will I do this in JavaScript function SetVal(val)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a protected class variable in your *.aspx.cs*-file and reference that variable - inside your JavaScript function - in your *.aspx*-file:

**.aspx.cs:**

```
public partial class X : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected String useMeInJavaScript = "";
}
```

**.aspx:**

```
<script>

SetValue(<%= useMeInJavaScript %>)

</script>
```

*Note: this is pretty simplified, but I'm sure you get the point.*

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, I would have thought that you would need something like the following

```
function SetValue(elem, val) {
        elem.value = val;
}
```

and then use like so

```
var element = document.getElementById('id_of_element');
SetValue(element, 'Value to Set');
```

**EDIT:**

if you wanted to make the SetValue function specific to only setting the value of one element (which I wouldn't really recommend - it would be better to write a generic function rather than tie the function to one specific element), you could do the following

```
function SetValue(val) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('id_of_element');
    elem.value = val;
}
```

Comment: of course, this will need to load when the DOM has loaded and the id_of_element will need to be the ClientID of the control if it is a server control and is a child of any other class that implements INamingContainer